# Error no match for 'operator *' (operand type is <clase>)

Tags: c++, punteros, template

Tengo el siguiente codigo que realiza la busqueda en orden Posterior de un arbol:

```
template<class T>
Lista<NodoArbol<T>>* Arbol<T>::ordenPosterior(NodoArbol<T>*origen,Lista<NodoArbol<T>>* OPos){
while(1){
    NodoArbol<T>* siguiente = *origen->getSiguiente();
    if(siguiente->getElemento()!=nullptr){
        ordenPosterior(siguiente,OPos);
        OPos->add(siguiente,OPos);
    }else{
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Tengo la funcion getSiguiente definida de esta manera:

```
template <class T>
NodoArbol<T> NodoArbol<T>::getSiguiente(){
   return this->hijos->getValor(this->hijos,siguiente++);
}
```

En la lista de hijos de NodoArbol meto referencias de NodoArbol para poder acceder a los hijos de ese nodo, el problema se presenta en la linea:

```
NodoArbol<T>* siguiente = *origen->getSiguiente();
```

Con el siguiente error:

```
..\src\Arbol.h:78:29: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'NodoArbol<Vertice>')
```

Soy algo nuevo en esto de los objetos en C++ y creo que tengo un problema de referencias pero no se como identificar cual notacion debo usar si la referencia a la clase o el apuntador a la referencia

Comment: En la definición de `NodoArbol<T>::getSiguiente()` se dice que devuelve un objeto de tipo `NodoArbol<T>`. mientras que en `NodoArbol<T>* siguiente = *origen->getSiguiente();` se espera que devuelva un puntero a puntero a un `NodoArbol<T>`. Eso no está bien.

Comment: Ya lo cambie y aun me sigue dando error ahora en la parte de retornar por valor en el elemento de la lista

Comment: @asdasdasd ¿ Porqué no escribes un respuesta ? Tu comentario era acertado y solucionó el problema. **AngelBulnes**: Si tienes un nuevo problema, formula una nueva pregunta e indica los detalles relevantes: código que te genera el error, el contexto necesario, y, muy importante, el error **exacto** que obtienes.

Answer (score 2):

El error es claro y autoexplicativo, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> `error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'NodoArbol<Vertice>')`

> `error: no hay coincidencia para 'operator*' (el tipo del operando es 'NodoArbol<Vertice>')`

Este error viene a decir que el compilador ha intentado usar el [operador de des-referencia](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) (`*` unario) sobre el objeto `NodoArbol<Vertice>` y no ha podido. Esto puede deberse a:

1. `NodoArbol<Vertice>` no es un tipo que nativamente soporte el operador de des-referencia.
2. `NodoArbol<Vertice>` no dispone de un operador de des-referencia definido por el usuairo.

Es sin duda el segundo caso, los únicos tipos que soportan la des-referencia de manera nativa son los punteros y `NodoArbol<Vertice>` no es un tipo puntero, así que sólo nos queda el segundo caso.

---

Seguramente querías acceder al nodo como tal, dado que `getSiguiente` devuelve el nodo, ya lo tendrías:

```
    template <class T>
    NodoArbol<T> NodoArbol<T>::getSiguiente(){
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Devuelve Nodo, no devuelve puntero-a-Nodo!
       return this->hijos->getValor(this->hijos,siguiente++);
    }
```

```
//   Sin des-referenciar --> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    NodoArbol<T> siguiente = origen->getSiguiente();
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~ Nodo, no puntero-a-Nodo
    if(siguiente.getElemento()!=nullptr){
//              ^ <-- punto, no flecha
        ordenPosterior(siguiente,OPos);
        OPos->add(siguiente,OPos);
```